# call code behind event if clicking on a non-server control hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net, click, code-behind

If you have a standard hyperlink...

```
<a href="somelink"> message </a>
```

...and this link is **not** inside a form runat="server" tag,
and you can't put it inside one, either, would you know of 
any possible way to tie the click event for this tag to a 
code-behind method?

Answer (score 2):

To call a server side method on a client side event you need to do the following:

1- Create the server side method:

```
void DoSomething(...) { ... }
```

2- Implement the `System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent` which take one string argument (You can assign the name to the value of this argument).:

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument) 
{
        DoSomething(...);
}
```

3- Write a script to trigger post back:

```
function TriggerPostBack(control, arg){
    __doPostBack(control, arg);
}
```

4- Call the PostBack trigger function when needed:

```
<a .... onclick="TriggerPostBack('control', 'arg')" .. />
```

Comment: One note: there must be at least one visible control in the Form that can cause a PostBack(f.e. a TextBox with `AutoPostBack=True`).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: If I got you right, you can add the __doPostBack function manualy too..